# Cannot get data from input variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, each

I have data from code javascript like this

```
var params_1 = document.getElementById("params_1");
var params_2 = document.getElementById("params_2");
var line_1 = params_1.options[params_1.selectedIndex].text;
var line_2 = params_2.options[params_2.selectedIndex].text;
```

That is method for get data from select options in javascript, and I get data like this in `console.log()`

```
line_1 = "CPM"
line_2 = "CPA"
```

In my thinking, I can make a dynamical looping with that variables like this

```
var data_ln_1 = [], data_ln_2 = []; 
chart_1 = [object{CPM = 12, CPA = 13}, object{CPM = 13, CPA = 14}]
chart_1.forEach(function (i) {    
            data_ln_1.push(i.line_1);  
            data_ln_2.push(i.line_2);  
        });
```

it must be get an array like this

```
data_ln_1 = [12,13];
data_ln_2 = [13,14];
```

but the result just in `[object, object]`

I get confused on this, but when i change the code into

```
chart_1.forEach(function (i) {    
        data_ln_1.push(i.CPA);  
        data_ln_2.push(i.CPM);  
    });
```

I get the result `data_ln_1 = [12,13]`

But if I using this, that not running dynamically

Can anyone give me some advice for running the looping dynamically, so I no need to make `if` into `each`.

Comment: Do you mean "dynamically"?

Comment: Sorry for my english :D
thank you :)

Comment: There is no such property as "line_1" or "line_2" in your "i" object. That's why it doesn't work. How about i[0] and i[1]?

Comment: First of all, you might have better success debugging if you name your variables more descriptively.

Comment: I tried to using i[0] & i[1], but the result in console.log is _undefine_

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, the code should be like this

```
chart_1.forEach(function (i) {    
        data_ln_1.push(i[line_1]);  
        data_ln_2.push(i[line_2]);  
    });
```

So I can found my array like this `data_ln_1 = [12, 13]`